# How to list packages with files in a particular directory?

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, rpm

I'm switching to CentOS from another distribution, and I'm not used to working with `yum`. I'd like to know if there's a way to know which installed packages have files in a directory.

For example I'd like to know which packages have files within `/usr/share/applications`.

Looking at what `yum` provides I saw there's a way to see installed packages (list installed) but even providing `-q` doesn't get me just the names of the packages. I saw no option to list contents of a single package however.

Is it possible? How could I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this using `yum` but you can craft a `rpm` command that will do mostly what you want. You'll have to utilize the `--queryformat` option and iterate through the array of filenames using the little known option `[..]` in the `--queryformat`.

**NOTE:** All these features are discussed in the manual for RPM, [Maximum RPM: Taking the Red Hat Package Manager to the Limit](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/).

```
$ rpm -qa --queryformat '[%{NAME}: %{FILENAMES}\n]' | \
    sed 's#\(/.*/\).*$#\1#' | sort -u | grep '/usr/sbin' | head -10
abrt-addon-ccpp: /usr/sbin/
abrt-addon-pstoreoops: /usr/sbin/
abrt-addon-vmcore: /usr/sbin/
abrt-dbus: /usr/sbin/
abrt: /usr/sbin/
alsa-utils: /usr/sbin/
aoetools: /usr/sbin/
at: /usr/sbin/
authconfig: /usr/sbin/
avahi-autoipd: /usr/sbin/
...
```

#### Details

The above `--queryformat` iterates over the array macro `%{FILENAMES}` via the `[...]` notation, printing the name (`%{NAME}`) of the package they're contained in, along with their full installed path.

*Example*

```
$ rpm -q --queryformat '[%{NAME}: %{FILENAMES}\n]' fatrace
fatrace: /usr/sbin/fatrace
fatrace: /usr/sbin/power-usage-report
fatrace: /usr/share/doc/fatrace-0.5
fatrace: /usr/share/doc/fatrace-0.5/COPYING
fatrace: /usr/share/doc/fatrace-0.5/NEWS
fatrace: /usr/share/man/man1/fatrace.1.gz
```

With this type of output we simply need to chop off the trailing filenames from the above paths. For this I used `sed`.  I then run the output through `sort -u`  to condense any duplicate lines since often times, many packages will install a multitude of files into a single directory. Finally I use `grep ...` to find the packages which have files in a given directory. To facilitate this further you could do this:

```
grep $(pwd)
```

*Example*

```
$ pwd
/usr/sbin

$ rpm -qa --queryformat '[%{NAME}: %{FILENAMES}\n]' | \
    sed 's#\(/.*/\).*$#\1#' | sort -u | grep $(pwd)
```

#### A list of just package names

To get just the names of the packages in a unique list you can do the following:

```
$ rpm -qa --queryformat '[%{NAME}: %{FILENAMES}\n]' | \
    sed 's#\(/.*/\).*$#\1#' | sort -u | grep $(pwd) | \
    awk -F: '{print $1}' | head -10
abrt-addon-ccpp
abrt-addon-pstoreoops
abrt-addon-vmcore
abrt-dbus
abrt
alsa-utils
aoetools
at
authconfig
avahi-autoipd
```

#### References

- [The Parts of an RPM Query](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-query-parts.html)
- [A Few Handy Queries](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-query-handy-queries.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it appeared to be rather convoluted when I first saw the command but I understand it now. I had to add a `| uniq` in the end not to repeat package names in your last suggestion.

Comment: @Carlos - hmmm, the `sort -u` should have collapsed the list.

Comment: It works fine as long as there are just one file per package in the directory, I just realized that moving the `| sort -u` part to after the call to `awk` is enough to output package names without repeated occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know which packages have files within /usr/share/applications

You can query for what package owns a particular file by doing a `rpm -qf <absoluteFilePath>`. To do an entire directory tree you can use the `find` command and filter the output.

For example:

```
[root@xxx01 ~]# find /usr/share/applications -type f -exec rpm -qf {} \; | grep -v "is not owned by any package" | sort | uniq 
firefox-31.1.0-5.el6_5.x86_64 
savui-1.0.14-13.i386 
shared-mime-info-0.70-4.el6.x86_64 
[root@xxx01 ~]#
```

> I saw no option to list contents of a single package however.

This is a slightly different option with `rpm`. For example to list what files are in the `firefox` package:

```
[root@xxx01 ~]# rpm -ql firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
/usr/lib64/firefox
/usr/lib64/firefox/LICENSE
/usr/lib64/firefox/application.ini
/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/blocklist.xml
/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/chrome
/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/chrome.manifest
/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/chrome/icons
/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default
/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default16.png
/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default32.png
/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default48.png
/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/components
/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/components/components.manifest
/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/components/libbrowsercomps.so
/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/defaults/preferences
/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/extensions
/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}/icon.png
/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}/install.rdf
/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/icons
/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/icons/mozicon128.png
... snip ...
```

Comment: Thanks that was enlightening, I though only `yum` was used for packaging but it appears to be a frontend mostly. Your solution to the problem relies on the files being present in the system: if you delete the files of a package it wouldn't tell you that the package has files in that directory.

Comment: Ah well you used the present tense in your post so I had assumed you were trying to assess the impact of some operation or something. Either way, there you go.

Answer (score 1):

The answer slm is almost correct, maybe it's outdated. The best script I have is the following:

```
rpm -qa --queryformat '[%{=NAME}: %{FILENAMES}\n]' | grep ' /var' |  cut -d: -f 1 | uniq
```

Notices that the meat of this is almost like the one above, the '=' make the NAME an iterator also.

Comment: Strangely this worked on Fedora 39 and not the accepted answer. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

To see what package *provides* a particular file or directory you can use `yum provides <file>`:

```
$ yum provides /usr/share/applications/*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fedora: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * rpmfusion-free-rawhide: mirrors.coreix.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-rawhide: mirrors.coreix.net
 * updates: ftp.uni-koeln.de
abrt-gui-2.3.0-3.fc21.x86_64 : abrt's gui
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/share/applications/abrt-applet.desktop



alacarte-3.11.91-2.fc21.noarch : Menu editor for the GNOME desktop
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/share/applications/alacarte.desktop
```

and it goes on and on.  Pipe it to `less` to read it.

To list the files in a package, simply use `rpm -ql <package>`

```
$ rpm -ql less
/etc/profile.d/less.csh
/etc/profile.d/less.sh
/usr/bin/less
/usr/bin/lessecho
/usr/bin/lesskey
/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh
/usr/share/licenses/less
/usr/share/licenses/less/LICENSE
/usr/share/man/man1/less.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/lessecho.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/lesskey.1.gz
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although `whatprovides` wouldn't be enough if the files were non present (e.g. if they were deleted). Thanks for the `rpm` command as well, I was just using `yum`.

Comment: I beg to differ - `yum provides | whatprovides` even works to find a package for a known, but uninstalled, file/directory. For example, `yum provides /usr/share/doc/lshw` will show that this is part of the `lshw` package even if it hasn't ever been installed.